# How to write headless Puppeteer/Cypress E2E tests for Dapps

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethers.js

I'm trying to write E2E tests for my Dapp in which I also want to interact with the contracts on local/test chains. I've managed to do this with Metamask but the issue is that [I'm not able to run it headless](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#working-with-chrome-extension), I was wondering if there is any other solution to this.

What I have so far basically is that I'm [loading the Metamask](https://dev.to/ajaykumbhare/load-chrome-extensions-in-puppeteer-4fk0) inside puppeteer with

```js
[
  `--disable-extensions-except=${process.env.METAMASK_PATH}`,
  `--load-extension=${process.env.METAMASK_PATH}`
]
```

but it's not ideal because I have to specify different paths on different machines (using .env for this). And inside the browser I'm simply navigating to the extension url's to onboard and do the transactions as I would on a normal page i.e.

```js
await page.goto('chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/home.html', { waitUntil: 'load' }
```

The onboarding takes a lot of time without headless and I'm unable to run it inside CI/CD without a fake display (using Xvfb) and lot of setting up as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51683309/3528132).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at dappeteer or synpress?

https://github.com/chainsafe/dappeteer

https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress

Comment: afaik both of those options essentially do the same thing as what I was going for and don't work headless

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a headless library for that

https://github.com/cawabunga/headless-web3-provider